# Matlab: Random list of stimuli from folders with different probabilities

Tags: matlab, random, probability, directory, weighted

I have a several folders with subfolders containing stimuli and want to generate a randomized list of these stimuli.  The subfolders are called '1', '2','3', according to stimulus priority. Also, the final list should have a certain percentage of stimuli from each folder.

Example:
40% from 'Flowers',
20% from 'Cactuses',
10% from 'Trees',
30% from 'Fruit'.

Fruit contains subfolders like 'Berries', 'Citrus', 'Stone Fruit', which have equal probability.

All folders contain these subfolders 1, 2, 3. First, stimuli from 1 should be used. Each stimulus should be presented exactly once. Only when there are no more stimuli in 1, stimuli from 2 can be added, and so on.
The probability distribution is only important in the beginning. If one folder runs out of stimuli, that's fine.
How can I implement the probabilities/weights of folders and priorities of subfolders?

Here an example of my folder structure:

```
Stimuli/Flowers/1
Stimuli/Flowers/2
Stimuli/Flowers/3
Stimuli/Trees/1
Stimuli/Trees/2
Stimuli/Trees/3
Stimuli/Fruit/Berries/1
Stimuli/Fruit/Berries/2
Stimuli/Fruit/Berries/3
Stimuli/Fruit/Citrus/1
Stimuli/Fruit/Citrus/2
Stimuli/Fruit/Citrus/3
```

each folder contains files as stimuli.

---

my thoughts, very basic so far:

```
%get all files in a folder
sfolder='Stimuli/Berries/1';
stim=dir(fullfile(sfolder,[*.png]));
stim={stim(:).name};

stim=stim(randperm(size(stim,2)));  %randomization.
```

I just tried this, which gives me the probabilites for the folders:

```
fs=dir('Stimuli');
fs={fs(:).name};
fs=fs(3:8);
weightvec=[0.2,0.4,0.3,0.1];
nofsamp=50;
chos=randsample(fs,nofsamp,1,weightvec);
```

Comment: 1) Could you give a concise but complete example of your folder structure? Are "stimuli" files? 2) What does the priority of subfolders do? I got a hard time to realize that.

Comment: 1) I added an example of my folder structure. Yes, stimuli are files.
2) First, files from a folder with top priority (1) should be used, only when there are no files left, files from the next folder should be used.

Comment: I will try to define a class object that does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Define a class object `foo` to handle the job.

Note the inheritance of `handle` since the methods will change the properties.

```
classdef foo < handle

    properties
        category
        priority
        name
        selected
    end
    methods (Static)
        function obj = parse(dirpath, files)
            N = sum( cellfun(@(x) length(x), {files.name}) );
            obj = foo.empty(N,0);
            counter = 0;
            for ii = 1:length(files)
                ff = files(ii);
                if ~isempty(ff.name)
                    fp = strsplit(strrep(ff.path, dirpath, ''),'/');
                    for jj = 1:length(ff.name)
                        counter = counter+1;
                        obj(counter) = foo( fp{1}, fp{2}, ...
                            regexprep(ff.name{jj}, '\.txt$', '') );
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    methods
        function obj = foo(c, p, n)
            if nargin>0
                obj.category = c;
                obj.priority = p;
                obj.name = n;
                obj.selected = false;
            end
        end
        function obj = choose(stimuli)
            has_delegate = 0;
            while ~has_delegate
                cat = unique({stimuli.category});
                sub = false(3,length(stimuli));
                rcat = randi(length(cat));
                sub(1,:) = ismember( {stimuli.category}, cat(rcat) );
                rpri = 0;
                while ~has_delegate && rpri<3
                    rpri = rpri+1;
                    sub(2,:) = ismember({stimuli.priority}, num2str(rpri));
                    has_delegate = any(~[stimuli( ...
                        all(sub(1:2,:),1) ).selected]);
                end
                if has_delegate
                    sub(3,:) = ismember( [stimuli.selected], false );
                    delegate = find(all(sub,1));
                    rnam = delegate(randi(length(delegate)));
                    obj = stimuli(rnam);
                    stimuli(rnam).selected = true;
                end
            end
        end
    end

end
```

### Create class object arrays in main script.

Uses 2 libraries [`countmember`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7738-countmember) and [`dirwalk`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32036-dirwalk-walk-the-directory-tree).

```
clear;clc;

% import file names
dirpath = '/home/user/Downloads/S/';
[t_np, t_nd, t_nf] = dirwalk(dirpath);
files = arrayfun(@(x,y) struct('path',x,'name',y),t_np,t_nf);
% create stimuli structure
stimuli = foo.parse(dirpath, files);

% choose stimuli
M = 10;
select = foo.empty(M,0);
t_ii = 1;
while t_ii<=M
    select(t_ii) = stimuli.choose();
    t_ii = t_ii+1;
end
disp({select.name}')

% stats of category
t_stcat = {select.category};
stats = {unique(t_stcat), countmember(unique(t_stcat), t_stcat)};
for t_ii = 1:length(stats{1})
    fprintf('%2.2f %% from \''%s\''.\n', ...
        stats{2}(t_ii)/M*100, stats{1}{t_ii})
end
clearvars t_*
```

### About file names

Depending on your OS, you need to change the file paths and predecessing folder path.

- In main script, change `dirpath`.
- in class definition `foo`, change the directory delimiter `/` and file extension `txt` written in the static method `parse`.

### Output

```
    'oak'
    'lily'
    'ash'
    'banana'
    'sunflower'
    'rose'
    'hazel'
    'cedar'
    'cherry'
    'maple'

30.00 % from 'Flower'.
10.00 % from 'Fruit'.
60.00 % from 'Tree'.
>>
```

Comment: thanks alot! The selection from folders works just as I intended.
Where can I predefine the percentage of stimuli selected from a folder? So that I can meet the 40% from 'Flowers', 20% from 'Cactuses', 10% from 'Trees', 30% from 'Fruit'.

Comment: okay, I added my weight vector to the choose function, so I can influence the percentage. 

    %  rcat = randi(length(cat)); %replaced with
     rcat=randsample(length(cat),1,1,weightvec); 

So far, the code only selects certain folders. As soon as I get the Fruit folder with its subfolders working, everything should be fine.

Comment: `if length(fp)<=2

     obj(counter) = music_select( fp{1}, fp{2}, ...
         regexprep(ff.name{jj}, '\.wav$', '') );

 else

     obj(counter) = music_select( [fp{1}, '/', fp{2}], fp{3}, ...
         regexprep(ff.name{jj}, '\.wav$', '') );`

Comment: How is `weightvec` defined?